# Nginx + Slim route POST data

Tags: php, post, nginx, url-rewriting, slim

I have an issue configuring Nginx correctly to work with Slim POST route.

In a post here on StackOverflow it was said that it is not a good practice to rewrite POST request.

Post: [nginx rewrite post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795068/nginx-rewrite-post-data)

The idea is to have http://someurl.com/scan which is a POST route in index.php and allow only POST requests on the /scan and deny everything else.

index.php:

```
$app->post('/scan', function(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) { ... }
```

My Nginx conf looks like this:

```
server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  someurl.com;

       index index.php;
       root /var/www/maxime/public;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/max.err
       access_log /var/log/nginx/max.log

      location / {
          deny all;
      }

      location = /scan {
          limit_except POST {
              deny all;
          }
         rewrite ^/scan$ /index.php last;
      }

      location ~ index\.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass php_pool;
          fastcgi_keep_conn on;
      }
}
```

To me this conf tells me that if a request is done on /scan and it is a POST request then we "redirect" everything to /index.php. Then the index.php location block comes into action which passes everything to the index.php or am I mistaking somewhere?

Currently with this setup I get this error in Nginx:

> *100778 readv() failed (104: Connection re
>   set by peer) while reading upstream client: 123.123.123.123, server: someurl.com,
>    request: "POST /scan HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "someurl.com"

Comment: That linked question is not relevant as you are using `rewrite ... last` which does not redirect. The `connection reset by peer` is probably a script error upstream.

Comment: @RichardSmith I think this is more a problem of Nginx configuration as I have another server block for every call from inside the company which works perfectly, only the server block of the outside domain is probably not correctly configured. (And yes firewall is correctly setup to reach the correct server, it used to work before)