# nginx redirect POST requests

Tags: nginx

I have a web server which accepts `https://www.example.com/API/ooo/xxx`, `https://www.example.com/API/aaa/bbb`, and `https://www.example.com/API/xxx/yyy` ... etc.

Now we want to redirect the above quests to `https://www.example.com/ooo/xxx`, `https://www.example.com/aaa/bbb`, and `https://www.example.com/xxx/yyy` ... etc.

I've tried using `rewrite` key word in nginx:

```
location /API/ {
    rewrite ^/API(.*)$ https://$host$1 redirect;
}
```

This works for GET requests. But it turns POST requests to GET requests. This is something I don't want.

How can I preserve the http method while redirecting `/API/*` to `/*`?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795068/nginx-rewrite-post-data) says that I can use `307` redirect. But `rewrite` doesn't seem to support `307` redirect. And I can't figure out how to use `$1` regular expression property in `return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `return` statement. You can use a regular expression `location` block to capture the part of the URI to return.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/API(/.*)$ {
    return 307 $1$is_args$args;
}
```

Note that with the regular expression `location` directive, its order within the configuration is significant, so you may need to move it. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But `return 307 $1$is_args$args;` redirects POST `https://www.example.com/API/ooo/xxx` to POST `http://www.example.com/ooo/xxx`. Is it possible to preserve the `https` protocol?

Comment: I've tried `return 307 https://$1$is_args$args;`. But this doesn't work. It redirects POST  `https://www.example.com/API/ooo/xxx` to POST `https:///ooo/xxx`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have an AWS application load balancer sitting between the client and nginx. The load balancer receives https requests and send http requests to nginx. That's why I need to add `https` protocol.

Comment: Try `return 307 $scheme://www.example.com/API/ooo/xxx/$1$is_args$args`