# How to make Python Requests follow a POST redirect?

Tags: python, redirect, post, python-requests

Using the following code, the server responds with a 301 redirect, but the client changes POST to GET, which is useless behavior because that GET endpoint does not exist. Using CURL -L -X POST  works properly. This behavior is the same using python2 and python3 and on several versions of Raspbian.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://registry.micronets.in/mud/v1/register- 
device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg"
>>> response = requests.post(url)
>>> response
<Response [404]>

# Server Log: (Note - both endpoints, are on the same server using virtual hosts)
redirecting to: https://hotdawg.micronets.in/registry/devices/register- device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg
POST /registry/v1/register-device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg 301 16.563 ms - 122
{
  "status": 404
}
GET /vendors//register-device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg 404 0.604 ms - 14

# CURL version (succeeds)
curl -L -X POST "https://registry.micronets.in/mud/v1/register- 
device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg"
Device registered (insert): {
  "model": "AgoNDQcDDgg",
  "pubkey": "aabbccddeeffgg",
  "timestamp": "2019-12-27 15:44:14 UTC",
  "_id": "HBlQzXfBnoB3N4fN"
}

# Server Log: (from CURL)
redirecting to: https://hotdawg.micronets.in/registry/devices/register- 
device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg
POST /registry/v1/register-device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg 301 0.364 ms - 122
POST /vendors//register-device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg 200 1.745 ms - 157
```

Comment: have you tried using the `allow_redirects` flag to `True` in your `POST` request

Comment: (I suspect the issue is that the redirect is to another domain (actually a subdomain). I would speculate that the POST redirect would succeed if redirecting to a different endpoint on the same domain). As mentioned, both endpoints are on the same physical server, mapped using virtual hosts in nginx. So the IP address for both endpoints is the same

Comment: aws_appentice I will try that but I read that that is the default behavior except for HEAD requests. Yes, just tried it, same behavior

Comment: also as a side note, this is a `POST` request with no body? that seems weird

Comment: aws_appentice we do that all the time. The POST changes data on the server, but the data is in the URL

Comment: Just figured out the `stream` cut-off after redirection which means the `nginx` is not configured correctly ! means that we got response `301` and then `404` !

Comment: @aws_apprentice what?

Comment: how do you know the nginx is not configured correctly? OP does not show his config

Comment: @aws_apprentice Just captured the packet sent, and checked the response. we got `301` and then `404` which means the redirection is completely dropped off ! that's lead that the final end point is requiring something ! such as body or data or specific cookies !

Comment: if the nginx wasn't configured properly then the `POST` request from the shell wouldn't work either, however it does

Comment: X is calling Y, and then Y is calling Z, where Z is refusing the call due to invalid content of the call.

Comment: @aws_apprentice the `OP` stated that `both endpoints are on the same physical server, mapped using virtual hosts in nginx. So the IP address for both endpoints is the same `  which means the POST request already reached the first source and got a response of 301 which redirecting to the second source. so here's the issue, the second source is configured wrongly ! we are sending POST request which the redirect moved it to GET request ! I've dealing with several issues same as this before !

Comment: especially the redirection on same server holding same `IP`, which the `ETag` will completely be identical .

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη If the server was configured incorrectly, then why does `curl -L -X POST` work just fine?

Comment: @svenyonson Well, let me explain for you. your first call is completely valid ! and you got a response of `301` then the call been redirected to the second source which is final end point and here you have the issue !

Comment: Both are on the same server ! with the same IP-Address, so the content of the header and ETag is completely the same ! how the end point will define it's POST or GET ? !!

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη the 301 redirect from the server specifies only the URL, not the method. The method is chosen by the client when the redirect is followed

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Because the requests are going to a virtual host, which sees the domain in the url and maps it as as configured - it does not route based on the IP address. But, as I mentioned, and aws_apprentice mentioned, curl and python are both clients, issuing the same exact request. One works, one does not, the server is the same in both cases

Comment: @svenyonson check my answer.

Comment: Others have suggested a workaround for the situation where the redirect is initiated from nginx itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795068/nginx-rewrite-post-data. However, in my case the redirect is originating in my node.js server like so: `res.redirect(301, redirectURL);`

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather accept a better answer, but otherwise I plan to work around the problem as follows:

```
response = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False)
if response.status_code == 301:
    response = requests.post(response.headers['Location'])
```

## or

```
response = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False)
i=10
while i > 0 and response.status_code == 301:
    response = requests.post(response.headers['Location'], allow_redirects=False)
    i -= 1
```

Comment: what is the new here ? calling the header location. is that's all ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη the new here is that it solved my problem. It also demonstrates that there is nothing wrong with my nginx configuration

Answer (score -3):

Check your `nginx` configuration: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795068/nginx-rewrite-post-data)

1. You've already sent a `POST` request which is already reached the server successfully.
2. Now the server is handling the `POST` request and handling it according to your assigned rules.
3. Here's the issue occurred as the redirection assignment on your configuration is calling the end [url](https://hotdawg.micronets.in/registry/devices/register-device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg') by `GET` request.
4. You are blaming `requests` that it's not handling the redirect but it's already handled it correctly. but you compare it to `curl` which you used with it `-L` which is force the server the server by default to push the request. (etc, `curl --list-only -X POST "https://registry.micronets.in/mud/v1/register-device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg"`) where you are using `-X` which is for `HTTP` over an `HTTPS` url.

`-X, --request will be used for all requests, which if you for example use -L, --location may cause unintended side-effects when curl doesn't change request method according to the HTTP 30x response codes - and similar.` <<< Pay attention to the part of `curl doesn't change request method` which is `POST` in your case and already forced the server with it. but for `requests`it's completely different thing.

[image]

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as ses:
    r = ses.post(
        "https://registry.micronets.in/mud/v1/register-device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg", allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.history[0].headers['Location'])
```

Output:

```
https://hotdawg.micronets.in/registry/devices/register-device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg
```

> at the end, i do believe this nginx server which is behind linode servers, and that's a common issue.

the knowledge is here:

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as ses:
    r = ses.post(
        "https://registry.micronets.in/mud/v1/register-device/DAWG/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg", allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.history, r.history[0].reason)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Output:

```
[<Response [301]>] Moved Permanently
404 Not Found
```

But `POST` To it !

```py
r = requests.post(
    "https://hotdawg.micronets.in/registry/devices/register-device/AgoNDQcDDgg/aabbccddeeffgg")
print(r)
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Which confirm that you sent `POST` request and it's completely switched to `GET`.

with that said, as i explained above that `curl -X` is set to force the server with the method used which is `POST` till the end point.

Comment: this still returns a `404` and does not answer OP's question