# Python requests redirect to GET instead of POST

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to call the url of a REST API for which both GET and POST requests are possible. I want to send a POST request. If I run my request through the ThunderClient plugin everything works fine. I can send a POST request and get the correct data.

If I send my request in python like this:

```py
    import requests
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data=payload,
        verify=certificate,
    )

    pprint(response.request)
```

It will print `<PreparedRequest [GET]>`. The requests library redirects to send a GET and I will get the corresponding GET response.

If I set `allow_redirects=False`:

```py
    import requests
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data=payload,
        allow_redirects=False,
        verify=certificate,
    )

    pprint(response.request)
```

It will print `<PreparedRequest [POST]>`, but I get an empty `response.text` and this header:

`{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-length': '0', 'Location': '...url...', 'Connection': 'close'}`

and status code 302.

I don't have this issue when I send the POST request through ThunderClient. I just get the expected data back.

What I am doing wrong here? How can I ensure that I send a POST request?

Comment: anecdotally, try adding or removing a trailing `/` from the URL - some servers are especially picky about it .. what happens if you go to the Location field? (do check the domain for security awareness too..)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Python Requests follow a POST redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503317/how-to-make-python-requests-follow-a-post-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

The exact behaviour of status 302 is implementation defined.

> 302 Found (Previously "Moved temporarily")
> Tells the client to look at (browse to) another URL. The HTTP/1.0 specification (RFC 1945) required the client to perform a temporary
> redirect with the same method (the original describing phrase was
> "Moved Temporarily"),[11] but popular browsers implemented 302
> redirects by changing the method to GET. Therefore, HTTP/1.1 added
> status codes 303 and 307 to distinguish between the two
> behaviours.[10]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection

It is possible that some implementations use GET redirect while other use POST (original method) redirect. Use status 303 for GET and 307 for original method.

Comment: I don't have control over the server side software. How do I get python to use POST after the redirect? Is there a way to find out where the redirect leads, so I can directly get query this address?